# Android - saving an image to internal storage and loading it into an imageview as part of another activity

Tags: image, android-intent, save, android-image, android-file

My app has a camera button. Upon click this button launches the native camera app and the user can take a picture. If the user accepts the picture (taps check mark) I want to start a new activity which will display that image on a new screen. I am trying to save the image like so: File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), filename); and then get the file path and pass the path on as a string to my new activity. In my new activity I am attempting to retrieve the filepath from the previous intent, and use that to load the image into an ImageView. Before I write the bit to load the image into the ImageView I wanted to check that the filepath string is being passed by printing it in a text area on the new screen. Unfortunately, it does not appear to be passing properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is a snippet of my code. Many thanks in advance for the assistance!

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_use_camera);

        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        //start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    String filename = "myfile";

        //make sure the user clicked to accept the picture in the native camera app
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
            { 
                //save image internally 
                File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), filename);
                //get the filepath
                String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                //create the swatchintent
                Intent Swatchintent = new Intent(this, DisplaySwatchActivity.class);
                //pass filepath to the intent
                Swatchintent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, filepath);

                //start the intent
                startActivity(Swatchintent);
            }
        }   
    }
```

then, my next activity:

```
public class DisplaySwatchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_swatch);
        String filepath = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(UseCameraActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        textView.setText(filepath);

    }
```

Comment: If you run the debugger, do you see the `filepath` variable contents get set in `DisplaySwatchActivity`? It could be that the text is too long for the `TextView`.

Comment: yes, it looks like it is there..coming as "/data/data/com.example.insieme/files/myfile" I did not realize there was a character limit for the textview - do you still think that could be the problem? Maybe it's better to just try to load the image itself into an imageview instead of taking this intermediate step. I am very new to this so I appreciate your help.

Comment: Not that the text view cannot take the number of characters, but that the layout of a long string pushes it off the screen -- it is there, but cannot be seen.